# Многострочный текст в заголовке appbar'а

Tags: android

Как сделать текст в заголовке аппбара многострочным, к примеру в 2 строки?
Вот код аппбара в xml:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_set"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_set"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_size"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Стиль текста c попытками сделать его многострочным :

```
  <style name="ToolbarTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
        <item name="android:singleLine">false</item>
        <item name="android:minLines">2</item>
        <item name="android:lines">3</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/actbar_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    </style>
```

и строчка в коде где я задаю текст для аппбара :

```
setTitle("start" + " - "  + "\n"+ "end");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете попробовать программно так:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title));
toolbar.setSubtitle(getResources().getString(R.string.subTitle));
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Или добавьте в тулбар `TextView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Первого варианта хватило.

Comment: Если ответ верный, отметьте пожалуйста галочкой слева от сообщения.